# Using imagemagick how can i slice up an image into several separate images?

Tags: bash, imagemagick, crop, slice

Please consider following example:

[image]

The source image consists of 6 areas that need to be sliced up into 6 separate images.

How can I get the desired output using imagemagick. I tried to understand a possible solution presented in the imagemagick [examples](http://imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile), but failed to transfer it to my specific problem.

What would be a way of solving this problem preferably in a one-liner?
Since all the areas which i want to slice have the same size, but only differ in their offset, is there a way to somehow pass a preset area size, and then simply add the xy-offset for each area?

Comment: How do they differ in offset? Arbitrarily placed? A grid starting at an origin? Basically, how do the offsets of the areas relate to each other?

Comment: here placed script that can do what u need:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63774378/automatically-extract-tiles-from-comics/77201321#77201321

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If each area has the same amount of padding around it, you can use [the `@` operator](http://imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_spaced).

This cuts an image into 6 sections, 2 per row, with 40 pixels of horizontal padding and 20 pixels of vertical padding excluded from each section:

```
convert image.png -crop 2x3-40-20@ +repage +adjoin tile-%d.jpg
```

Comment: Can I do this but starting at `%d` =1 ?

Comment: Yes, see [fx expressions](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php) and [filename percent escapes](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#save_escapes) --

`convert image.png -crop 2x3-40-20@ -set filename:index "%[fx:t+1]" +repage +adjoin tile-%[filename:index].jpg`